# Clustering over several excel documents with the same columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I have a task that requires to cluster data from several excel documents with ability to look afterwords from which document data was taken.

The problem is that I do not have an idea how to excract data from these files and memorize from which file data was extracted.

Let's say, I have 3 columns in each excel document (col_1, col_2, col_3) and I need to cluster the data.

I was searching for similar problem in the internet, but no results..

Any help would be helpful!
Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask for solutions on homework or projects, so you might be disappointed with this question. I suggest learning some basic python and Pandas, try something yourself then come back to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to merge multiple Excel files into one data source and feed that into some kind of clustering algo.  Is that correct?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import glob
glob.glob("C:\\your_path_to_all_files\\*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:\\your-path_to_all_files\\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    print(all_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    # df.shape
    # df.to_excel("C:\\your_path_to_all_files\\final.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
    # only if you want to save the merged files into a new Excel file...
```

Start KMeans Clustering below . . .

Since you didn't include a dataset, I'll give you a simple one here, for learning purposes.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
# %matplotlib inline
from sklearn import datasets#Iris Dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data#KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
km.fit(X)
km.predict(X)
labels = km.labels_#Plotting
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(7,7))
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, 0.95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)
ax.scatter(X[:, 3], X[:, 0], X[:, 2],
          c=labels.astype(np.float), edgecolor="k", s=50)
ax.set_xlabel("Petal width")
ax.set_ylabel("Sepal length")
ax.set_zlabel("Petal length")
plt.title("K Means", fontsize=14)
```

[image]

```
###################################################

from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
#%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import datasets#Iris Dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data#Gaussian Mixture Model
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=3)
gmm.fit(X)
proba_lists = gmm.predict_proba(X)#Plotting
colored_arrays = np.matrix(proba_lists)
colored_tuples = [tuple(i.tolist()[0]) for i in colored_arrays]
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(7,7))
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, 0.95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)
ax.scatter(X[:, 3], X[:, 0], X[:, 2],
          c=colored_tuples, edgecolor="k", s=50)
ax.set_xlabel("Petal width")
ax.set_ylabel("Sepal length")
ax.set_zlabel("Petal length")
plt.title("Gaussian Mixture Model", fontsize=14)
```

[image]

FYI, there are several alternative clustering algos available in the Scikit Learn library.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have already figured out how to merge excel files together. Now, I have another problem. The type of my data is following: object_1 has three attributes: attr_1, attr_2 and attr_3. Each attribute is presented as an array of data points that belong to the object. So, I need to cluster objects depending on content of attributes. Is it possible? I saw many examples, but attributes were presented as a single number, not an array. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about this?

data = np.asarray([np.asarray(DF['attr_1']),np.asarray(DF['attr_2']),np.asarray(DF['attr_3'])])

Comment: Exactly about this

Comment: Please go ahead and up-vote my original post if it helped you out.